# SQL running total is different from real running total

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have these 2 columns in my SELECT:

```
a.Sales,
sum(a.Sales) over(partition by FiscalYearNum,FiscalMonthNum,StoreName order by [Historical Date]) Sales_MTD
```

Then I summarized both of them by [Historical Date], calculated the running total of June Sales, and compared it with June Sales_MTD. There are discrepancies from June 15.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: provide sample data and expected output in tabular form.

Comment: What database app are you working with? Please add that tag.